# Clicking the "replied to" icon does nothing when the message is selected

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

When I click on the replied to icon in the mobile chat interface when I have a message selected, I expect something to happen, for instance, selecting the message that was replied to or (less desirable) opening the transcript to that message.  Instead, nothing happens.  I can long press to bring up the context menu and go to the message in the transcript, but that's a lot of work just to see what a reply was to.

Comment: Insert "The goggles, they do nothing!" joke here.

Comment: Works for me. Do you have any userscript installed?

Comment: Okay, it works when I don't have a message selected, but if I do have a message selected, nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a bug.

When selecting a message, it means we want to perform some action on that message (edit/delete if own message, reply if written by others, etc) hence the action icons lit up.

Seeing the target of a reply-to message is not really an action on the message itself, so it's totally expected not to  "work" when the message is selected.